# Edit just a sheet in a big (>30 MB) Excel File using POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a >30MB Excel (.xlsm <- yes, -xlsM) file that contains roughly 30 sheets (so the size of each sheet is rather small).

Whenever I'd like to modify data in that file, I only want to access one of the sheets in it. So there is basically no need to have enough memory for holding the whole file, just for one sheet.

My question is, if it is possible to just read one sheet of such Excel file, in order to modify it and store it back into that file?

I believe, I read something like that sheets in an Excel file are different zip packages contained in the Excel File container. But I cannot find that information anymore (which makes me think, I just made it up myself because it sounds so nice ;-) ).
If this is really the case and there is a way to just get the zipped sheet (which, again, is rather small), then I should be able to modify it without the need of much memory and processing power, right?
Is this possible?

Thanks,
Maik

Answer (score 0):

Excel uses a compressed file format, that can be unzipped (or inspected) with .zip file compatible tools. You will find many files within the Excel package. Apache POI takes transparently care of the unpacking and packing of the file. Indeed, each worksheet is represented as an individual XML file. I wouldn't worry about POI loading all worksheets into memory, while you are working on only one. Or are you already experiencing memory issues?

Comment: First of all, I'm experiencing long processing times. In fact, the call to "XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new File("test.xlsm"));" takes a huge amount of time (10 seconds and more). This is way too long for the task I try to solve.
So if there is a way to only access the compressed part of the sheet I really need to get my hands on, I hope I can reduce this access time dramataically.
Again, the question is: is this possible and if so, how...?

Comment: There is a lot of overhead, when the "POI stuff" initializes. Subsequent calls to new XSSFWorkbook should be much faster. Did you try that?

Comment: Well, I just once tried to perform the above call and let it finsih... (yes, I admit I was unpatient before...)
Now, I indeed get an "out of memroy" Exception after I waitet almost a minute...
I just unziped the xlsm file with 7zip and the resulting folder is 250 MB.
I found a tool named "OpenXmlFileViewer_1.0.0.2" which gives a very good overview of the file contents and I believ that it should not be impossible to extract a sheet from such an Excel File. But I have to admit that I have not the slightes clue, on how to do it with POI, or if it is even possible.

Comment: Just for completenes: I use "-Xmx1024M" and get:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.NamespaceContext$NamespaceContextStack.<init>(NamespaceContext.java:78) at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.NamespaceContext$NamespaceContextStack.<init>(NamespaceContext.java:75) at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.NamespaceContext.getNamespaceContextStack(NamespaceContext.java:102)
....